# Migrating Play! application from scala 2.10 to 2.11

Tags: scala, playframework

I decided to move from play 2.2.0 and scala 2.10.2 to play 2.3.6 and scala 2.11.4.
If I updated play(version of some dependencies, such as sbt-plugin and play-java-jdbc) everything works fine. But when I set scala version to 2.11.4 a get following error:

```
[error] /Users/user/my-play-project/conf/routes: routes is already defined as object routes
[error] /Users/user/my-play-project/conf/routes: routes is already defined as class routes
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed 09.11.2014 4:52:44
```

So, may be somebody knows, what's happening?
I tried do clean and manual removing all targer directories, but it didn't help.

Comment: Try to remove manually all `target` directories. In linux `find . -name target | xargs rm -Rf`. I receive similar errors, but after deep clean all was fine. I never deep for a problem reason. Try to reproduce scenario, create similar project on github and create a issue on playframework.